# Is there a way to reset/kill TCP connections on Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, networking, tcp

I've been struggling with finding a way to simply reset/kill a TCP connection with one command. Let's say I have 3 Virtual Machines running Ubuntu 18.04. VM1 is the gateway, VM2 is a host, and VM3 is an attacker. If VM3 connects to VM2 through SSH, is there a way I can see that through VM1 and then reset/kill the TCP connection?

I heard *netstat -atnp* is used to see connections on the local machine but I can't see the SSH connection between VM3 and VM2 from VM1. I also discovered that *tcpkill* can be used to kill the connection, but I'd be looking to automate this using a Python3 script. Based on my understanding, it looks like *tcpkill* will control the session terminal until I *CTRL+C*. As a result, I'm not sure if this can be implemented into a script since I'd have to manually *CTRL+C* while the script is running.

Answer (score 2):

netstat is only able to show connections where one endpoint is the local machine, i.e. where there are local sockets involved. It does not show connections where the local machine simply forwards packets, like done in the case of passing packets between to virtual machines.

Assuming that in your case all packets from VM3 (attacker) to VM2 (host) pass through VM1 (gateway) - which might be true or not based on your description. In this case the traffic can be observed on VM1 and regulated for example with iptables. iptables could limit what traffic is possible in general or it might kill connections by injecting RST based on specific events - see [How to reset a tcp connection immediately on both ends on a certain condition using linux netfilter/iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/538692/how-to-reset-a-tcp-connection-immediately-on-both-ends-on-a-certain-condition-us). One could also sniff the traffic and kill selected connection with tools like tcpkill as you already noticed. These tools also inject a TCP RST to kill the connections. There are other tools like this, some are also written in Python and thus maybe easier to integrate. See for example [here](https://gist.github.com/spinpx/263a2ed86f974a55d35cf6c3a2541dc2) or [here](https://github.com/robert/how-does-a-tcp-reset-attack-work/blob/master/main.py).